# Load .txt file form javascript and using localStorage

Tags: javascript

I wanna ask about using ActiveXObject and using localStorage.

In my project, I'm using ActiveXObject to load .txt file.(In local not on server)
and later I have to use localstorage but IE can't use localstorage. 
but On server it's works However if I use server i can't use ActiveXObject...

So Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title> test </title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var ct = localStorage.getItem("ct"); 
    if(ct == null) ct = 0; 


  function readFile(filename){
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var ForReading = 1;
    var f1 = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForReading);
    var text = f1.ReadAll();
    f1.close();
    return text;
  }

    read = setInterval(function(){

      number = readFile("C:/rec_dice/numberOf.txt");
      split = number.substring(0,1);
      console.log("st point : " + split);
    },1000);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST for stn</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt that you are allowed to read/write on C from the web ("server").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't a good way to access a local file if you are using javascript in a browser. If its just a text file on the same machine without a http/webserver you may run into some problems, as in javascript the ability to read a local file is disabled by default in most browsers. In chrome you can disable this security-feature by adding the following flag when starting the browser from command-line.

--disable-web-security

If your data is structured json, xml, csv, you can bring it in using an AJAX call if the file is hosted on a server accessible with HTTP. Without using an http ajax call, another possible solution as mentioned in the question link above:

Just an update of the HTML5 features http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ This excellent article will explain en detail the local file access in Javascript. Summary from the mentioned article:

The spec provides several interfaces for accessing files from a 'local' filesystem:

File - an individual file; provides readonly information such as name, file size, mimetype, and a reference to the file handle. FileList - an array-like sequence of File objects. (Think or dragging a directory of files from the desktop). Blob - Allows for slicing a file into byte ranges. -- @Horst Walter
As shown below you can have a "file upload" input selection, and simply have your file path as a default option for the input"

Answer (score 0):

Your localstorage for your local attempt to run the script is different when you access "the same" script from the server. Therefor you get displayed two different localstorage. This is intented for security reasons. You dont want foreign websites to have access on 3rd party content.